# Online Shop Using JavaScript

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am attempting to create an online shopping application using JavaScript where it is possible to both create an item and also to create and view all orders that have been made.

I have written the following code thus far:

```
IndexPage.jsp

<html>
<head>
    <title>Order Item Editing</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the Online Supermarket</h1>
<h2>Please select one of the following options</h2>
<div>
<a href="/items/" class="btn btn-default">Items</a>
<a href="/orders/" class="btn btn-default">Orders</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>



 itemHomepage.jsp

 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Summary of Items</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>Item Information</h2>
 <section>
 <a href="/item/itemDetails" class="btn btn-default">Add a new item</a>
 <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">Return to the home page</a>
 <p/>
 </section>
 <section>
 <table class="TFtable">
 <tr>
   <td><h3>Item Id</h3></td>
   <td><h3>Name</h3></td>
   <td><h3>Description of Item </h3></td>
   <td><h3>Cost</h3></td>
   <td><h3></h3></td>
  <td><h3></h3></td>
 </tr>
<c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="item">
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${item.getItemId()}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${item.getItemName()}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${item.getItemDescription()}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${item.getItemCost()}"/></td>
<td><a href="/item/itemDetail?itemId=${item.getItemId()}">Edit Item</a></td>
<td><a href="/item/delete?itemId=${item.getItemId()}">Delete Item</a></td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
 </section>
 </body>
 </html>
```

itemDetail.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Edit Item </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Add Item Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" commandName="item" action="/item/add">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="itemId">Id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="itemID" readonly="true"/></td>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="description">Description</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="description" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="cost">Cost</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="cost" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

OrderHomepage.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Summary of Orders</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Summary of Orders</h2>
<section>
<a href="/order/detailsOfOrders" class="btn btn-default">Add a new order</a>
<a href="/" class="btn btn-default">Return to the Homepage</a>
<p/>
</section>
<section>
<table class="TFtable">
<tr>
  <td><h3>Order Id</h3></td>
  <td><h3>Total Cost</h3></td>
  <td><h3></h3></td>
  <td><h3></h3></td>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${listOfOrders}" var="order">
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${order.getOrderId()}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${order.getOrderCost()}"/></td>
    <td><a href="/order/detailsOfOrders?orderId=${order.getOrderId()}">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="/order/delete?orderId=${order.getOrderId()}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

detailsOfOrders.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Order Information</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Order Information</h2>
<table>
<form:form method="POST" commandName="order" action="/order/addOrder">
  <tr>
    <td> <form:label path="id">ID: </form:label> </td>
    <td> <form:input path="id" readonly="true"/> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form:form>
<section>
<a href="/itemDetail" class="btn btn-default">Add new item</a>
<a href="/order/" class="btn btn-default">Show all orders</a>
<p/>
</section>
<table class="TFtable">
<tr>
  <td><h3>Item Id</h3></td>
  <td><h3>Name of Item</h3></td>
  <td><h3>Price</h3></td>
  <td><h3>Amount</h3></td>
  <td><h3>Total Cost</h3></td>
  <td><h3></h3></td>
  <td><h3></h3></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a controller as shown:

```
package eMarket.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import eMarket.EMarketApp;
import eMarket.domain.Product;
import eMarket.domain.Order;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listOfOrders", EMarketApp.getShop().getlistOfOrders());
        return "form/orderHomepage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/orderDetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String orderDetail(@ModelAttribute("order") Order order, @RequestParam(value="orderId", required=false, defaultValue="-1") int orderId) {
      if (orderId >= 0) {
        // modify
        Order o2 = EMarketApp.getShop().getlistOfOrders().stream().filter(o -> (((Order) o).getId() == orderId)).findAny().get();
        order.setId(o2.getId());
      } else {
        // add
        order.setId();
      }
      return "form/orderDetail";
    }
```

ItemController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import eMarket.EMarketApp;
import eMarket.domain.Product;
import eMarket.domain.Order;
import eMarket.domain.Item;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/item")
public class ItemController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listOfItems", EMarketApp.getShop().getListOfProducts());
        return "form/productHomepage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String productMaster(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, Model model) {
        EMarketApp.getShop().getListOfProducts().removeIf(p -> (p.getProductId() == product.getProductId()));
        EMarketApp.getShop().getListOfProducts().add(product);

        model.addAttribute("itemList", EMarketApp.getShop().getListOfProducts());
        return "item/itemDetail";
```

For some reason, when I attempt to an an item to a new order, I am not re-directed to the itemDetail page. Please could you advise where I am going wrong?

Comment: this is not related to Javascript

Comment: `jsp` stands for "Java Server Pages", not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the class level @RequestMapping for your ItemController is has a value of /item like @RequestMapping("/item") as shown by

```
    <a href="/item/itemDetails" class="btn btn-default">Add a new item</a>
```

in the itemsHomePage.jsp.

I propose you do the following:

1. Change the 'Add new item url' in detailsOfOrders.jsp (to start with **/item**) from

   ```
   <a href="/itemDetail" class="btn btn-default">Add new item</a>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <a href="/item/itemDetail" class="btn btn-default">Add new item</a>
   ```
2. If problem continues, then try to have c:url values as href values like:

   ```
   <a href="<c:url value = '/item/itemDetail' />" class="btn btn-default">Add new item</a>
   ```

Comment: The problem still arrises: perhaps the issue lies somewhere in the ItemController?  (See code edit above).

Comment: Would you mind to share the snippet of the item controller?

Comment: I have included it at the bottom of the question above.

Comment: If itemDetail page is located in the form directory, in add of ItemController call 'return "form/itemDetail"; instead of return "item/itemDetail"; '. If this fails, kindly share the Web Config and your webapp folder structure showing where the jsps are located.